# Combining firebase observables with angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'm working on an angular2 - firebase app, and was wondering on some best rxjs practices, that I find difficult to google.

Say I have a class "Project" with properties like "name", "$key", etc. And then also arrays of "Note[]" and "Task[]"

"Note" and "Task" are then their own classes.

Initially I structured data in firebase like this:

- Project

  - Name
  - Tags
  - Other meta stuff
  - Tasks

    - Task1
    - Task2, etc
  - Notes

    - Note1
    - Note2, etc

I would get one data stream and use map to get the data to look exactly how I want it.

But then I realised that this is bad practice and the project trees should be as flat as possible so that I wouldn't be forced to load everything when I just need the project metadata for example.

So I restructured it to be like this:

- Projects

  - Project1

    - Name
    - Tags
    - etc
  - Project2

    - Name
    - Tags
    - etc
- Tasks

  - Project1

    - Task1

      - Name
      - Body
    - Task2

      - Name
      - Body
  - Project2

    - Task1

      - Name
      - Body
    - Task2

      - Name
      - Body
- Notes

  - Project1

    - Note1

      - Name
      - Body
    - Note2

      - Name
      - Body

So this way I get three data streams of "Projects" "Notes" and "Tasks".
It seems to make sense to combine this into a single stream of "Projects" with "Notes" and "Tasks" inside it.

Although I'm unsure of what's the best way to do that? 
I wrote a long function that concatMaps everything into and array of "Project[]", but now I'm left with an array instead of a stream, which definitely seams wrong.

Or maybe it's a wrong approach altogether?

Looking forward to your thoughts.
Thanks!
H

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your structure exactly but if you have "Projects" "Notes" and "Tasks" as three separate streams (I guess this means you have three Observables). You can use [`merge()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-merge) or [`concat()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat) to consume whichever values comes first from any of them or consume one Observable at the time respectively:

```
let obs1 = Observable.from([1, 2, 3]).map(v => Observable.of(v).delay(1000)).concatAll();
let obs2 = Observable.from(['a', 'b', 'c']).map(v => Observable.of(v).delay(1000)).concatAll();

obs1.concat(obs2)
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));

obs1.merge(obs2)
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/TLxg1jOuhAN6U8xoQJIo?p=preview

The first example with `concat()` prints:

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

The second example with `merge()` gives:

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
```

I think you should understand the difference.

Don't mind the complicated operator chaing for `obs1` and `obs2`. It's just to emit each value with delay to simulate asynchronous streams.